# Addressing issue in flash M29W800DB

Tags: c, flash

I wanted to loop through the addresses in that flash M29W800D, so I started a counter from 0 to 0xFFFFE, then I try to write an unsigned int to an address, but it fails. When I made the loop counter to increment each even addresses, it worked.
but why ? what's so special with that chip that doesn't address all the addresses ?

here is a link to the datasheet http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/M/2/9/W/M29W800D.shtml
I'm using blackfin 533 with the chip.
I'm using 16 bit mode with the flash

Comment: Nowhere near enough useful info in your question. What does "but it fails" mean? Are you using this flash IC in 8-bit or 16-bit mode? What micro/processor are you using? How are you driving the address lines? Where is your schematic? How about a link to the datasheets?

Comment: @brhans I modified the question, please talk a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you set chip into 8-bit mode (/BYTE is low), and try to access it using 16-bit data bus.

Comment: In that case, I have to use even addresses ? but why ?

Comment: How do I know? You did not provide circuit diagram and information on how you access the chip. The only my educated guess as you state about even addressing was that you use chip in wrong data mode.

Comment: I use 16bit databus, with 8bit mode